mongo-go-driver retry cursor.Next() after error
Update: it is now confirmed that the issue occurred because of networking problems, i.e. a misbehaving load balancer, which would randomly transmit incomplete BSON strings. The problem has been solved by fixing the load balancer.
When iterating a Mongo collection using mongo-go-driver v1.15.0, I'm randomly getting BSON decoding erorrs during cursor.Decode, such as error decoding key accoun: EOF. Note that the name of the key is in fact account_id. It appears that the BSON data does not get transmitted completely, probably due to networking issues.
I have no control over the network in this setting, but I own the application. To ensure the application runs successfully every time, the only option seems to retry upon these errors, until the underlying errors have been resolved.
Update: restarting the iteration as a whole is not an option, because the underlying networking issues will hit during the next try as well.
The important bits of my code look like this:
cursor, err := db.Collection(`c`).Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{})
Check(err)
defer cursor.Close(context.TODO())
for cursor.Next(context.TODO()) {
    var doc bson.M
    err := cursor.Decode(&doc)

    Check(err) // this sometimes fails with decoding errors

    // do something with the result
}

The cursor in mongo-go-driver fetches documents in batches. So I assume, if cursor.Decode() fails, simply retrying decoding won't help, because the current batch of documents is incomplete.
Rather, the faulty document must be fetched again and replaced. Is there a way of achieving this in mongo-go-driver, to mitigate random networking errors while iterating a Mongo cursor?
I'm looking for something along the lines of:
err := cursor.Decode(&doc)
if (err) {
    cursor.RetryDocument()
    continue
}


I work with docs in huge sizes and many docs in query results. I've never encountered such issue. Not sure how your setup looks like but my objects and their corresponding mappings with labels look like the ones in this example if it helps. I suspect it will but maybe try refactoring your code to see if anything changes. e.g. using structs instead of var doc bson.M.

Thans for your reply @BentCoder. The code has been running in production for 5 years, without error. The application did not change, but after problems with the infrastructure, these errors started occurring. We have been analyzing this thoroughly, I have been building large-scale data integrations for many years myself. There is some problem with the underlying network/resources/... I am looking for a way to retry fetching an erroneous document with a cursor, see original question.

Are you absolutely positively sure that you have network problems? Or have you deduced that from MongoDB's or your application's behavior? Also, the setup might be of importance. How many mongos instances? Are they running on the application server or dedicated host? How large is the data set and the change set? How many shards? What is the shard key? What are the configured timeouts? What does the monitoring data say?

Not sure whether it's network problems. But I'm sure it's not the application, because that has been running since 2019 and started crashing a month ago, without changing it. The database did not change either. I'm not in charge of the database, but it is maintained by professionals who are maintaining hundreds of apps, which are part of a large companies online portfolio. The errors we are seeing are all due to incomplete BSON data. We implemented a retry mechanism for bulk updates, running them again helps. Therefore we would like to do the same for cursors.
